# Keycloak Kerberos prevent login dialog

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak, kerberos, spnego

I'm using [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) to manage authentication of a java-based web-application. 
I configured a Kerberos *User Federation* which is working fine within the internal network. 
Accessing the web-application from outside the network I get the following login dialog instead of being forwarded to the keycloak login form.
 Interesting the forwarding works with Firefox, but not Edge, Chrome, IE. 
How can I prevent the login-dialog and forward directly to the keycloak-login-form?

EDIT: For example would it be possible to create a second authentication flow (with kerberos disabled) and pass it as parameter in the URL?

The Authentication Flow:

- Kerberos - ALTERNATIVE
- Forms - ALTERNATIVE

[image: Browser Login Dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out, the browser-login-dialog is not shown and the flow is forwarded to the keycloak-login-page if the following settings are made.

- web-application URL is added to the "Trusted Sites" (either through IE settings or GPO) 
  EN: `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\Site to Zone Assignment List` 
  DE: `Computerkonfiguration\Administrative Vorlagen\Windows-Komponenten\Internet Explorer\Internetsystemsteuerung\Sicherheitsseite\Liste der Site zu Zonenzuweisungen`

[image: Kerberos GPO - trusted sites]

- the following GPO setting is made 
  EN: `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\Trusted Sites Zone` 
  **Logon options: Automatic logon with current user name and password** 
  DE: `Computerkonfiguration\Administrative Vorlagen\Windows-Komponenten\Internet Explorer\Internetsystemsteuerung\Sicherheitsseite\Zone vertrauenswürdiger Sites`
  **Anmeldungsoptionen: Automatische Anmeldung mit aktuellem Benutzername und Kennwort**

[image]

Comment: Hey, are you sure that the user is not getting authenticated with kerberos? Usually in such case browser will send the token automatically (without prompt). I see security vulnerabilities here.

Comment: Yes since "accessing the web-application from outside the network", I'm no user of the AD and hence not authenticated in through the AD.